# How to Hide HTML Table Columns using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I get dynamically generated HTML code like this,
**1.**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="title">Title</td>
        <td class="name">Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mr</td>
        <td>John</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mr</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Using this code I want to hide "Title" when sreen size 480, is it possible. If I have like following code I can easily do it,

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="title">Title</td>
        <td class="name">Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="title">Mr</td>
        <td class="name">John</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="title">Mr</td>
        <td class="name">Smith</td>
    </tr>
</table>

@media (max-width: 480px) {
        .title{
            display: none;
        }
}
```

**But top of the code *(1)* has class name only on first row. On that time how to hide complete column using first row class name.**

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly select the column based on it having something with .title in it. If the title row always comes first, you could use the selector `table tr:first-child` in your media query.